# nginx, php7.0-fpm and laravel, not able to set it up when the url has a prefix which the server doesn't have

Tags: nginx, php, docker, php-fpm

I am trying to set up a laravel installation in docker with php-fpm and nginx server on a separate container. The issue is the laravel is installed in a path like `/home/apps/foo` and the url I need is `abcd.com/v11/`. I thought this was fairly simple, but I am not able to set it up. Here is my location part in the nginx config

```
location /v11/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_pass php_wbv1.0:5000;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }
```

I tried rewrite tag, and tried giving alias inside the location block, both didn't work. The thing is if I remove the /v11/ from the location tag and the URL, its working without any issues.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: How is this different to your other question apparently about the same setup?

Comment: The other one was about making 2 locations work, I think I should just delete that because, I am not able to make even one work. so.